# Send a function, module to main via object Function node.js

Tags: node.js

I work on a server in node.js, and i'm quite new to the concept.
I'm using socket.io to communicate with clients
I have many modules in my server and i try to send a function declared in a module to my main. I don't want to use exports.plugin=plugin because I try to work with the observer pattern.

I tried :

In main.js:

```
//Modules NPM
var express = require('express');
var observer = require('node-observer');

//Extensions JS
var mymodule = require('./mymodule');
var plugin = require('./plugin');

 //Initialisation
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

...

```
socket.on('message', function (var1, var2) { //Come from client

    socket.var1=var1;
    socket.var2=var2;
    observer.send(this, "Message", "varSpecification");

});
```

In plugin.js :

```
//Modules NPM
var express = require('express');
var observer = require('node-observer');

//Extensions JS
var mymodule = require('./mymodule');
var main = require("./main");
```

...

```
observer.subscribe(this, "Message", function(who, data) { 

     var functionToSend= new Function ("varA", "varB"  ,"mymodule.function(varA, varB); socket.emit('messageOK');"); //I can't create a real function because i don't use socket.io in the module Plugin

     observer.send(this, "Response", functionToSend); });
```

Back to the main:

```
observer.subscribe(this, "Response", function(who, functionReceived) {

    functionReceived(socket.var1, socket.var2);  //Doesn't work

});
```

The problem is that when I execute the function in main.js, it doesn't find mymodule and can't execute the function associated.
(ReferenceError : mymodule is not defined)

When i execute the function directly in the main.js, it works.

```
observer.subscribe(this, "Response", function(who, functionReceived) {

    mymodule.function(socket.var1, socket.var2);  //Works

});
```

So I guess it's a problem with the object that I send

I will be more than grateful if you can help me!

---

EDIT : After other tests I found the source of the problem :

```
var mymodule = require('./mymodule');
```

...

```
mymodule.function(a, b); //works

var functionTest= new Function('mymodule.function(a, b)');
functionTest(); //Doesn't work (mymodule is not defined)
```

I still want to use the second option for my project but don't know how

Comment: Put a `module.exports = mymodule` as a last statement in your file where you have the `mymodule` declaration.

Comment: If I undestood well your answer  I already did it, and i can call my function in the main (last code). But "functionReceived(socket.var1, socket.var2);"still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try adding a `callback` to your `var mymodule` declaration like `var mymodule = require('./mymodule')(callback);` and see if it works?

Comment: Yes it works either in my main.js and my plugin.js so the problem is not from here

Comment: Thank you for helping me I think I will write another post more precise with my edit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the function constructor, and i didn't know that the function is declared in the global scope.

So i had to write this to make it work :

```
var functionTest= new Function('mymodule', 'a', 'b','mymodule.function(a, b)');
functionTest(mymodule,a,b);
```

I had to pass mymodule, a and b in parameter